# Installing 32-bit Java on 64-bit CENTOS: error java/lang/Object

Tags: java, linux, centos, 32-bit

I have a CENTOS box
 * release 6.5 final
 * Kernel Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
 * GNOME 2.28.2
 * Processor Intel Xeon
 * 64-bit

The 64-bit version of Java came included with the installation, as did Firefox.

I want to run a 32-bit Java application that I wrote, tested on Windows, on my CENTOS box, but am running into a problem.

I went to the java [download](http://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp) page and downloaded the 32-bit RPM version of Java, jre-7u45-linux-i586.rpm. I installed the package by opening up a terminal window, doing a su and entering the root password, and installed the RPM package. The installation went without a hitch.

I tried executing "java -version" from a terminal window (regular user or su makes no difference) and received some sort of elf error, which led me to a stack overflow issue that said to execute from a su'ed terminal window "yum install glibc.i686". I did that, but am now running into:

Error Message

```
[root@sarah-linux Downloads]# /usr/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin/java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

PATH

```
/usr/java/default/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/jmr/bin
```

CLASSPATH and JAVA_HOME

```
not defined
```

I also tried setting these two environment variables to

```
/usr/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin
```

but no dice, same problem.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back out the RPM install of the 32 bit Java.  You don't need it.  You can run 32 bit compiled byte code in a 64bit JVM.  Just can not do it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your jre class path.